# How to Ignore Case Cases

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How would I go about ignoring the case sensitivity in this code below? I have a list that's looking up a substring of a dataframe but I'm finding that it's case sensitive.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
data = ['Condor', 
        'Marmot',
        'Bear',
        'Condor a',
        'Marmotb',
        'Bearxyz']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["item_name"])

animal_list = ['Condor', 
               'Marmot',
               'Bear',
               'Pika',
               'Rat',
               'Racoon',
               'Opossum']
cond_list = [df["item_name"].str.contains(animal) 
             for animal in animal_list]

df["animal"] = np.select(cond_list, animal_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case=False`:

```
cond_list = [df["item_name"].str.contains(animal, case=False) 
             for animal in animal_list]
```

Or `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: Thanks! Unrelated question--how would I remove any blank spaces in a string from a dataframe? In this case, I'd like to remove any white spaces in df["item name"].

Comment: @doubledribble I suggest you to ask a new question next time, but I will help this time, you meant `cond_list = [df["item_name"].str.contains(animal.replace(' ', ''), case=False) for animal in animal_list]`

Comment: @doubledribble If my answer may have helped you, feel free to mark this as accepted by clicking the check mark (✔️), also feel free to upvote with the triangle pointing up. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information about accepting and upvoting answers.